# Error. no instance of overloaded function "strcpy_s" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, string

I get the error when I want to copy the source string which is a const char* into the destination string which is a char*. The code got no errors when I use strcpy() but to tell me it is deprecated. I mean, it doesn't have any problem with type of arguments.
And when I use the secure form(strcpy_s), it doesn't accept the type of destination string(char*).
I know i can use strdup() instead; but I actually want to know what's the matter with the type of destination string.

`const char* str1 = "test";
char* str2 = new char[strlen(str1) + 1];
char str3[5];
strcpy(str2, str1); // no errors. But it's deprecated
strcpy_s(str2, str1); // error. No instance of overloading function "strcpy_s".....
strcpy_s(str3, str1); // It works without any problem.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strcpy_s(str2, str1); this overload require size in bytes

```
strcpy_s(str2,strlen(str2) * sizeof(char), str1);
```